# Callback after adding tab to facebook page

Tags: facebook, tabs

For an application I am working on, I need to add a tab to a page on behalf of the user (with a bit of interaction from them).

Right now the only way I could find to do this is a redirect to
http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=APIKEY&pages=1&page=PAGEID&next=something

I need some feedback from facebook saying the page has been added - I thought the next parameter would cause a redirect but it doesn't. I also wanted to try opening a new window or using an iframe to do this in, and listen for the url to change, but I can't listen for cross-domain events.

Is there anything else I could look for to do detect this change, or an entirely different way to add tabs to pages, or am I going to need to add some kind of "click here after you authenticate" button?

Thanks!

Comment: Security on Facebook is very tight. They don't give you much control at all, and what you describe seems like something that Facebook doesn't want you to do. I'm not really sure so I'm not posting this as an answer. Actually when I think about it more, I could have sworn there was a post-add callback, but maybe not..

Comment: I think they handle adding tabs to pages differently than they used to handle adding tabs to your personal profile - perhaps there was a callback for that?

Comment: Having the same exact issue, will post an answer if I find out a way t do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by setting a post_authorize_redirect_url for your app. That url will get called every time someone authorizes your app and their profile id is included in the call. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954899/redirect-on-facebook-app-install/5718004#5718004) are some details.