# redirect on facebook app install

Tags: facebook

Upon install of my app on a Facebook Page, I'd like to send the user to an URL with further instructions. I'm starting the installation with http://facebook.com/add.php?api_key=app_api_key&page=page_id, which installs but redirects the user to the Facebook Page itself. It seems like various forms of redirect were available at some point:

- Post-authorize callback URL. I can no longer find that in App settings.
- The next parameter for add.php. I can't seem to get this to work

I have seen some apps that do redirect upon install, so I believe this is possible. Maybe it's using an old Post-authorize setting that's no longer visible?

Any help or point would be greatly appreciated! I'm also not attached to using add.php, if there's a Facebook Connect method that does this I'd use that instead (I'm looking at profile.addtab though that doesn't seem to work either).

Comment: I am trying to do just this. Have you figured out a way to redirect to the installed app page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the redirect URL in the app properties. You can no longer set it from the developer control panel in Facebook, but you can still set it using the REST api.

The list of app properties is here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appproperties/

To set the "post_authorize_redirect_url" you would use something like this:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/admin.setAppProperties?
  access_token=CURRENTTOKEN&
  properties={'post_authorize_redirect_url':'http://mydomain.com/post_authorize_folder/'}
```

I am not completely clear on this, but I believe the url needs to point to a folder, terminated with "/" rather than a specific file.

The callback gets two parameters:
installed = 1 (true)
fb_page_id = the page id when your app was installed

Comment: how do i get the access_token ?

Comment: @Yan: it depends on the language you're using but it's returned from a call to the graph api passing in your APP_ID and APP_SECRET. There are SDKs for many languages that include a wrapper for this here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/

Comment: i found it, you can get access token from here, and also set the properties through here 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/admin.setAppProperties/

Comment: something wired, when i set the propertiea and the callbacack and press "call method" it dosent work...

Answer (score 1):

First page that Canvas is point to should have
< script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = 'REDIRECT-URL';< /script>
So when your app is opened it will automaticaly redirect to REDIRECT-URL

I'm not sure that you can avoid opening of application canvas page after installing application.

Comment: Problem is the application tab isn't opened. It's going to the "Getting Started" page for the page owner.

Comment: When you are using 'next' param, what is the value.
Do you use full path as 'http://...'