# redirect user to application after adding app to a page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to catch the user event after the user adds my application to one of the user's fan pages and redirect the user to my application.

For example, I am calling this link "http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key={my_app_key}&pages" from my application, which will take the user directly to the face book custom selection page for adding the application to one of the pages of the logged in user. Once the user adds my app to one of the pages, by default face book automatically redirects the user to the fan page that he just added the application to. I am trying to catch the user after adding my application to his/her fan page and send (redirect) them to my application url with a query string parameter (page id).

Please let me know, if it is possible to specify this in the application settings or in any other way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the callback URLs that are set for your app. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954899/redirect-on-facebook-app-install/5718004#5718004).