# How to install an app on a user's page automatically?

Tags: java, facebook

I am writing an app where I am supposed to make a user to add my app to his page.

Right now if I want a user to make him add the app to his account I am simply redirecting the user to apps.facebook.com/myfunnyapp. From there on, facebook will guide him add the app to his account.

But I am supposed to make him add the app to his page.

Any ideas? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I don't understand. The whole point is so that you can't **force** anyone to do anything. I assure you it's quite deliberate on Facebook's part. Unless you're asking a different question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this url:

```
http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=<your_api_key>&pages
```

It will add your app to his *fanpage* automatically.

Comment: This is good, but it the page is showing me all my pages and apps and asking me to select anyone. What I want is not like this.

I will display all the pages a user has and an install button next to it. When that button is clicked the app must be installed to that particular page.

Many thanks for the reply. Can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Can you please look at this app, bandsintown. I want the UI to be like that.

Comment: I think you should create a page that require no-permission, and user can selects a side (fan or artist) like Bandsitown.

Comment: I dint understand what you are trying to tell

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. This post helped me

[redirect on facebook app install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954899/redirect-on-facebook-app-install/5718004#5718004)

We need to post a request to https://api.facebook.com/method/admin.setAppProperties?access_token=App_Token&properties={'post_authorize_redirect_url':'http://myhost.com/Test/callback.jsp?'}

Your app access token can be found here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/

Note: you have to use a app_token instead a user_token.

But what I need to know is will this app_token change every time or not?

Any ideas gurus?