# How can I make a Facebook app which redirects me to my website

Tags: facebook, web, e-commerce

How do you make a facebook application which you can search for on facebook and by clicking on it, it redirects you to a different website. An example is if you type in 1-800-Flowers and click on the App - it redirects you to the website http://ww30.1800flowers.com/template.do?id=template4&page=7900&conversionTag=true#flowers_facebook/offer straight away. Is this easy to do? If so, how? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954899/redirect-on-facebook-app-install

Answer (score 0):

You can start by creating a app on Facebook and point it to a page on your website. On the page, add [some JS code to pop](http://www.webniraj.com/2012/05/09/forcing-your-facebook-app-to-run-in-an-iframe/) the user out of Facebook and send them to your homepage: e.g.:

```
window.top.location = 'http://yourwebsite.com';
```

However, remember that it's against Facebook Terms to have an app simply redirect to a website. Your website must be Facebook Connected or use Facebook API in some way to enhance the user's experience.